# USB debug with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, adb

Unable to launch App in telephone device. Device is visible (ADB devices), debug USB on(in phone). In Eclipse I get the following timeout error:

```
[2010-10-14 14:07:30 - TA] Android Launch!
[2010-10-14 14:07:30 - TA] adb is running normally.
[2010-10-14 14:07:30 - TA] Performing com.xxxxx.ta.TA activity launch
[2010-10-14 14:08:00 - TA] Uploading TA.apk onto device 'HTXXXXXX'
[2010-10-14 14:08:05 - TA] Failed to upload TA.apk on device 'HTXxXXXXXX'
[2010-10-14 14:08:05 - TA] com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException
[2010-10-14 14:08:05 - TA] Launch canceled!
```

I installed/reinstalled drivers delivered in phone (HTC Wildfire) a couple of times..
At present the explorer hangs when trying to open the phone file system.
Running SDK-eclipse on Vista. 
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Plug and unplug the device; Restart the adb (don't know how to do it on win)

Comment: Plugging and unplugging device few times normally helps me.

Comment: Make sure your device is connected directly to your computer's USB port. I had a lot of problems when I connected it to USB port in my keyboard. All problems went away once I connected directly.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for encourage me to plug and unplug until feeling ridiclous.. :) It actually works now!!